# How can I make a new column and data frame with the percentage change from the start of a particular row in R?

Tags: r

Say for example I have the following data set:

```
wage <- c(2100, 2100, 2500, 2400, 2300, 2200, 2700, 2300, 2900, 3000)
timestamp <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

example <- data.frame(wage, age)
example
```

How can I make another dataframe which shows the percentage change from th starting wage, where I say which row is the starting wage. So say for example I want to start from row 3 and end at row 9. The first value is of course 0% change, which is the wage 2500, the next value will be (2400-2500)*100/2400 = -4%, the next value after that will be (2300-2500)*100/2300 = -8%, etc. for a total of 7 rows (row 3-9).

So it should look something like this:

```
timestamp    wage%change
3            0
4            -4
5            -8
6            -12
7            8
8            -8
9            16
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

start <- 3
end <- 9

example %>%
  slice(start:end) %>%
  mutate(wage_change = (wage - first(wage)) * 100/first(wage))

#  wage timestamp wage_change
#1 2500         3           0
#2 2400         4          -4
#3 2300         5          -8
#4 2200         6         -12
#5 2700         7           8
#6 2300         8          -8
#7 2900         9          16
```

Comment: Thanks, almost perfect! But how can I set the first wage (2500) as the standard/basis of the formula. So everything should be calculated with 2500 as the basis, your wage_change numbers are different from mine, because you use the previous wage and not the first wage (2500).

Comment: @henkjan Updated the answer. In the example calculation you shared you used `(2400-2500)*100/2400` , it should instead be `(2400-2500)*100/2500`

Comment: If I then do this:                  
example1 <- example %>%
  slice(start:end) %>%
  mutate(wage_change = (wage - first(wage)) * 100/first(wage)) ... 
ggplot(example1, aes(time, wage)) + geom_point ...
It gives the following error. 
Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): x = time. Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add stat()?
Do you know how to fix this, its like its non existent and not a new data frame?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question for this but you need to use columns that are present in your dataframe. There is no column with name `time` in `example1`. Perhaps, you meant `ggplot(example1, aes(timestamp, wage)) + geom_point()` ?

Comment: sorry, my mistake again, I indeed used timestamp instead of time.